# 1/3 of posts different class

Tags: wp-query, loop

Is there a way to count the amount of posts in a CPT and add a different class to 1/3 of said posts?

I am using Masonry for a grid and want two different image sizes displayed randomly. I got all that working but the images aren't aligning perfectly which is why the grid looks off (with gaps in between). I figured if 1/3 of the posts are smaller size it would align better.

So what I want is:

- Grid with two different image sizes that changes on refresh (so the layout is different with each refresh and the large & small images switch)
- The loop displays the items randomly

This is my current code:

```
        <?php
        /**
         * Template Name: Teampagina
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
         *
         * @package Deliciae Design custom
         * @since 1.0.0
         */

        get_header(); ?>

            <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>

                <?php astra_primary_content_top(); ?>

                <main id="main" class="site-main team-page" role="main">

                    <header class="entry-header <?php astra_entry_header_class(); ?>">

                        <h1 class="entry-title text-center" itemprop="headline"><?php echo post_type_archive_title(); ?></h1>

                        <form class="quicksearch">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="qs-input" placeholder="Zoek op naam">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </div>
                        </form><!-- quicksearch -->

                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'rand',
                        'post_type'  => 'focus_team'
                    );
                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    $count = 0; if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>


                    <ul id="team-masonry">
                        <li class="grid-sizer"></li>

                        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        ?>              
                            <li class="grid-item size-<?php echo rand(1,2); ?>">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <div class="fo--info">
                                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('team_member'); ?>
                                        <div class="fo--overlay">
                                            <div class="table">
                                                <div class="item">
                                                <?php the_title( '<h3 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">', '</h3>' ); ?>
                                                <p>functie</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </li>


                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?><!-- reset loop -->

                    </ul>
                <?php endif;?>

                </main><!-- #main -->

                <?php astra_primary_content_bottom(); ?>

            </div><!-- #primary -->

        <?php get_footer(); ?>

        <script>
        (function($){

            var qsRegex; 
            var $container = $('#team-masonry');

            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.grid-item'
            });

            var $grid = $('#team-masonry').isotope({
                resizable: true,
                  // set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
                itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                columnWidth: 300,
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
                },
              filter: function() {
                return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
              }
            });

            // layout Isotope after each image loads
            $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
              $grid.isotope('layout');
            });

            // use value of search field to filter
            var $quicksearch = $('input#qs-input').keyup( debounce( function() {
              qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
              $grid.isotope();
            }, 200 ) );


            // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
            function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
              var timeout;
              return function debounced() {
                if ( timeout ) {
                  clearTimeout( timeout );
                }
                function delayed() {
                  fn();
                  timeout = null;
                }
                timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
              }
            }

        })( jQuery );

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is in the comments:

```
<?php

...

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    //number of small ones needed = a third of total number of posts
    $numsmallneeded = round($query->post_count / 3);

    ...

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        //if no more small sizes are needed, use big
        if ( !$numsmallneeded ) $size = 1;
        //if number of small sizes needed = number of remaining posts, use small
        else if ( $numsmallneeded == $query->post_count - $query->current_post) $size = 0;
        //else pick at random
        else $size = rand(0, 1);

        //if small was picked, reduce number of small ones needed by 1
        if ( !$size ) $numsmallneeded--;

    ?>              

        <li class="grid-item size-<?php echo ++$size; /*add 1 before printing*/ ?>">

        ...

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?><!-- reset loop -->

                </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Also for the comments! Makes it a lot better to understand.

Comment: Inarilo, could you help me again, please? The code works and it looks pretty decent but somehow not everything gets placed perfectly. You can look at the demo here: https://dev.focusorange.com/team/ 
What do you think is wrong?

Comment: the number of posts seems to keep changing and the division seems to be more like 1/2 instead of 1/3? (i don't know if that is the issue)

Comment: It's 1/3. The number of posts are the same but they are currently adding the photo's which is why it could look off. Just wondering why I'm having gaps between some of the items.  This is the full code: https://gist.github.com/Deliciae/01af42e0433266250c3b9c6fa05bc207

Comment: Would I need to include Packery? When I use Layoutmode, the filter stops working and I can't seem to fix it... Can anyone help???

Comment: i think it has to do with the javascript algo that positions each item. perhaps you could put in a check to make sure that there is not more than x big ones between two small ones? but first try loading the correct size directly instead of loading all big ones and then resizing via css. you'll have to make sure those sizes are available and if not, then add them and regenerate the image files. then load the relevant thumb.

Comment: just saw your latest comment, i'm not familiar with packery, but you should create a new question if the above does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The `WP_Query` class offers both of what you are looking for:

By using `$query->post_count` you can get the total number of posts in your query.

By using `$query->current_post` you get the index of current post in the loop.

So, to check if the current post is in the first third of your total posts, you can use:

```
<?php if ( $query->current_post < floor( $query->post_count / 3 ) ) { echo 'some-class'; } ?>
```

Comment: This is really confusing for me. When I added the code it only displayed 3 posts. How do I output the whole loop and add a different class to 1/3 of them?

Comment: You should only put your class inside the brackets. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I added the code but it only adds the class to the first three posts. 

I want to add it to one third (33.33%) of the posts. How?